# nvidia in ubuntu, installed but not considered

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have `GP108BM [GeForce MX250]` in my ASUS laptop.
I installed the drivers from "additional drivers" and run several commands.

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
```

However:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108BM [GeForce MX250]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c4000000-c407ffff
```

You can see in `configuration driver=i915 latency=0`.
And in about/settings:

[image]

[image]

My plan is to use it mainly for fastai and pytorch (AI) but in anything else too.
It's in my understanding that drivers are installed but the system is not acknowledging the nvidia GPU as primary. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Hey @Terrance thank you for the suggestion. I tried secure boot and it's impossible to boot. It's stuck in the first screen forever. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, normally just disabling Secure Boot makes it so that the unsigned NVIDIA drivers load not that it prevents the OS from loading.  Is your Ubuntu set as the proper boot device in the BIOS?

Comment: I am not sure what proper device means. It's only ubuntu on my disk and I have partitions and everything. I purged nvidia and disabled secure boot and then it boot. Once I install the driver it's stuck again as soon as I switch it on.

Comment: Proper boot is mainly just that Ubuntu is the first boot in your BIOS.  I guess I am going to need to break out a UEFI system here and see if I can duplicate your issue.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I resolved it using the commands from this: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called/82686/7 I can't thank you enough @Terrance.

Comment: @Nmath thanks for your input, will update the answer right away.

Answer (score 3):

Steps followed:

Uninstalling NVIDIA driver

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

Disable secure boot.

Reinstalling the driver

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

thank you @terrance and post from:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called/82686/6